# Random output from database on click without reloading

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok so I have this website it's just a one page website with some text in the middle. How I have it set up right now is it's grabbing random text from my database with only one field in the table. And I echo that into a `<p>` element. Everything is working fine for that except that now I don't want to have to refresh the page every time to get a new text. I would like to be able to click a button and change the text without refreshing the page.

Here is the html it's pretty simple:

```
<p>
    <?php echo $story; ?>
</p>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_db   = "scary";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = ""; 
$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db) or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($link));  
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `stories`");
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$random_number = rand(0, $total_records - 1);
mysqli_data_seek($result, $random_number);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$story = $array['Story'];
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

I want to be able to click a button and change what is being echoed into the `<p>` without the page refreshing. How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: [**Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery. We have 2 files in this example: index.html and random.php.

index.html Source

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
          $("p").load("random.php",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt=="error")
              alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
          });
        });
    $("#button").click();   //loads random.php once at page load
    });
    </script>
   <p></p>
   <button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

random.php Source

```
<?
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_db   = "scary";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = ""; 
$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db) or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($link));  
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `stories`");
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$random_number = rand(0, $total_records - 1);
mysqli_data_seek($result, $random_number);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$story = $array['Story'];
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
echo $story;
?>
```

Note that both files have to be on the same directory/path. By the way if you want randomly get a row from mysql you can use this command instead of counting all rows than using rand() etc..:

```
SELECT * FROM `stories` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but doesn't seem to work I'm not getting any errors or anything just not working. double checked everything too.

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP code is working fine? What is the output if you directly open random.php like http://localhost/random.php ?